# How to reshape my trace arrays for standard scalar in Model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, reshape, numpy-ndarray

I'm working with seismic data to classify whether a trace is an earthquake, rockfall etc.

The data is in the shape shape=(629,3,15001) as there are 629 data points, 3 traces for every point (trace is a numpy array of time series data) and then (15001) which is the number of samples in each of those traces. How do I adapt this to change the data so that it can be better understood with a Keras model as currently I receive very poor results and hoping this will help.

Update: I can use the data as it is and receive a high accuracy with training but poor on testing. Therefore, this is why I'm looking to reshape the data to then use standardscalar on it. When attempting to use scalar directly, I get this error:

If I try scale I get this error without resizing

```
ValueError: Found array with dim 3. StandardScaler expected <= 2.
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked.

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
xTrain = scaler.fit_transform(xTrain.reshape(-1,xTrain.shape[-1])).reshape(xTrain.shape)
xTest = scaler.transform(xTest.reshape(-1,xTest.shape[-1])).reshape(xTest.shape)
```

Comment: it'll be very beneficial to future people if you add a few words on what actually fixed it.

Comment: The reshape in order to use the Scalar is in the answer